# Check if JButtons are within a particular JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, coding-style

I am creating a GUI application using Java. There are different sections in the main frame, each having a particular functionality. The header panel contains the buttons Submit, Undo, Shuffle, Help and Quit. Here is the sample code:

```
JPanel header = new JPanel();  

JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");  
header.add(submit);  

JButton undo= new JButton("Undo");  
header.add(undo); 

JButton shuffle= new JButton("Shuffle");  
header.add(shuffle);

JButton help= new JButton("Help");  
header.add(help); 

JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");  
header.add(quit);
```

Further down my code, I need to check that the button clicked is not in the header panel (there are buttons in other panels too).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      String clicked = e.getActionCommand();

      if(!clicked.equals("Submit") && !clicked.equals("Undo") && !clicked.equals("Help")&& !clicked.equals("Quit") && !clicked.equals("Shuffle")){  


      //some code here
```

Is there any alternate neater way to check that the button clicked is not in the header panel? I will need to do something similar in another panel which contains more buttons. Using IF statements to check for each button is inefficient and untidy, I believe.

Comment: Don't use the same callback for header panel buttons if you need to treat them differently; set a different `ActionEvent` listener

Comment: Use the event source and compare instances instead of Strings.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what is the problem you are facing. Using one action listener or multiple listeners has got nothing to do with the parent container that contains them. Why do you need to check whether the buttons are within a specific JPanel?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd just implement actions for every button. It may require more code but it's a better solution. But if you insist to go this way you can try this

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(PANEL.getComponents()).stream().filter(b -> b instanceof JButton)
            .map(b -> (JButton) b).filter(b -> 
                 b.getText().equals(e.getActionCommand())).findFirst().isPresent()) {
             // execute code if button is not a child of PANEL
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addActionListener` for every button separately.

Comment: I actually have added an ActionListener for each button, like this:  
`submit.addActionListener(this)`  
Am I doing something wrong?